# How to understand symbols in documentations

Tags: javascript, documentation, symbols

I'm trying to get a good sense of reading documentation instead of asking so many questions here and there.

The first thing i'm confused of is the symbols.What do the symbols below mean?

**example) app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])**

reference source:https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.use

*Question1&2 can be solve by the similar posting.*

- 3. Another example is like

> bisector.left(array, x[, lo[, hi]])

- what does **x[,** mean?
- what does **lo[,**mean?
- what does **,hi]** mean?

reference source: [https://devdocs.io/d3~5/d3-array#bisect](https://devdocs.io/d3%7E5/d3-array#bisect)

It would be very grateful if anyone could help me to under stand these cryptic symbols.

Comment: @jonrsharpe to some degree yes, but not fully. But thanks for the link

Comment: Then [edit] to clarify what else you want to know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think even if number 1&2 might be answered by the link you gave me while the number 3 quesiton can't be answered by the link, I think it's okay to leave number 1&2 as well to make it super crystal clear. If you don't like it, i can delete too. but it would be grateful if you allow me to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `[xxx]` means that this parameter is optional. You can use it or omit it.
2. `[callback]` is also an optional parameter. In this case it's a function that will be called under some circumstances.
3. Nested `bisector.left(array, x[, lo[, hi]])` means that you need to have some options before you can specify others. For example, you cannot specify `lo` in this case without specifying `hi` first.

Comment: How do i know "need to have some options before you can specify others"? since its written within x[ ]? or lo[ is opend square bracket??

Comment: In case of this example, you can know it by the fact that the square brackets are nested. Since `array` and `x` are mandatory, you have 3 options there: `array+x`, `array+x+lo`, and `array+x+lo+hi`

Comment: understood. but 1. how do I know which could be x like "x should be an array or x should be a string or just variable? 2. how do I know 'lo[, hi] means what could come within the optional bracket is [lo,hi]?If i understand it correctly. 3. what does the first comman mean within the bracket? , which is [,      before lo[, and hi]. the link jonrsharpe provided says , at the beginning means everything should be linked by ',' but i don't get the , within [ , lo[, hi] ]. Thank you a lot.

Comment: 1. This notation does not tell you the type of variable, it's usually written somewhere below in the docs; 2. Not sure I understand; 3. A comma is a delimiter between the arguments, when it's inside the bracket, it means that you add this comma only when adding an optional argument